# Raspberry Transmission-daemon doesn't restart automatically

Tags: services

I followed this guide:

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-torrentbox/

transmission works without problems but everytime I reboot the RaspberryPi I need to stop the service and then start again because it doesn't restart automatically.

With `sudo service --status-all` transmission-daemon has a "+" which should means that the service will start on startup. What to do?

Comment: Which step in the tutorial does it indicate that it will start on boot?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Raspbian Jessie add this to your /etc/rc.local file before "exit 0" string:

```
service transmission-daemon stop
sleep 10
service transmission-daemon start
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.